# Remove some features from sklearn PolynomialFeatures

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn module PolynomialFeatures to fit my model with polynoms over my datas.

To this extent I am doing the following :

```
P = PolynomialFeatures(3, interaction_only=False, include_bias=False)
model = make_pipeline(P, Ridge(tol=0.001, alpha=1, fit_intercept=False))
model.fit(initial_conditions, times_of_flight)
```

It works well and now I would like to be able to remove some of these features to refine my model. Say I would like to remove every features that contain one of the two first variables, x_1 and x_2, without the other.

I have tried to modify my PolynomialFeatures attributes (powers_, n_input_features_...) before fitting but Scikit returns me a sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError error.

How should I proceed ?

Comment: Not fitted error means you try to predict with a model that has not been fitted yet. If you have removed some features, fit the model, and then predict.